# How to find time difference between values present in two columns in a dataset in r

Tags: r, dataframe

Question:Data shared below contains two columns containing time in integer format but i have to convert it into proper time format i.e in hh:mm and do the difference between times and display it in mins

For Ex:value1:1715 in data should be converted to 17:15 value 2: 1709 should be converted to 17:09

once it is converted the difference should be calculated and if the value 2 time is more than 2 mins and if that is the case the value should be returned as 1 and in cases where the value2-value1 delay is less than 2 mins it should be returned as 0 and if value2-value1 is returned negative it should also be returned as 0,and if the difference is 0 it should be set to 0.

for the above mentioned data,value should be returned as 0 because value2-value 1 is returned negative.

```
structure(list(originaldata.df.schedtime = c(1455L, 1640L, 1245L, 
1715L, 1039L), originaldata.df.deptime = c(1455L, 1640L, 1245L, 
1709L, 1035L)), .Names = c("originaldata.df.schedtime", "originaldata.df.deptime"
), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the expected output should be something like below for the data mentioned in mydataset

```
Delay(>2 min)
0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your columns to proper datetime first,

```
d[] <- lapply(d, function(i) strptime(i, format = '%H%M'))

difftime(d$originaldata.df.schedtime, 
        d$originaldata.df.deptime, units = 'mins')

#Time differences in mins
#[1] 0 0 0 6 4

#or

as.integer(difftime(d$originaldata.df.schedtime, 
                    d$originaldata.df.deptime, units = 'mins') > 2)

#[1] 0 0 0 1 1
```